# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ } kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Full error stacktrace:

> 04-05 16:01:34.265 18746-18746/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>                                                      Process: com.example.mrathi.livedataviewmodel, PID: 18746
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.mrathi.livedataviewmodel/com.example.mrathi.livedataviewmodel.MainActivity}:
>   kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                       Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
>                                                          at com.example.mrathi.livedataviewmodel.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:40)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

---

Here is my database class with room api (In Kotlin using MVVM model)

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(BorrowModel::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    companion object {
        var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                **INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "borrow_db")
                        .build()** through target invocation exception
            }
            return INSTANCE as AppDatabase
        }
    }
    abstract fun itemAndPersonModel(): BorrowModelDao
}
```

Here is my activity code for observing database changes for UI updation:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() , View.OnLongClickListener {

    override fun onLongClick(v: View?): Boolean {
        val borrowModel = v!!.getTag() as BorrowModel
        viewModel!!.deleteItem(borrowModel)
        return true
    }

     var viewModel: BorrowedListViewModel? = null
    //  private var recyclerViewAdapter: RecyclerViewAdapter? = null
    // private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var users = ArrayList<BorrowModel>()
        var obj_adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(users, this);

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, 
        LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = obj_adapter
        try {
            viewModel = 
          ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BorrowedListViewModel::class.java)
        }catch ( e :Exception){
            e.toString()
        }


      viewModel!!.getItemAndPersonList()!!.observe(this, object : 
            Observer<List<BorrowModel>?> {
                override fun onChanged(t: List<BorrowModel>?) {
                    Log.v("OnChanged","OnChanged!!")
                    obj_adapter.addItems(t)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here is `ViewModel` class:

```
class BorrowedListViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private var itemAndPersonList: LiveData<List<BorrowModel>>? = null
    private var appDatabase: AppDatabase? = null

    init {
        appDatabase = AppDatabase.getDatabase(this.getApplication())

        itemAndPersonList = appDatabase!!.itemAndPersonModel().getAllBorrowedItems()

    }

    fun getItemAndPersonList(): LiveData<List<BorrowModel>>? {
        return itemAndPersonList
    }

    fun deleteItem(borrowModel: BorrowModel) {
        deleteAsyncTask(appDatabase!!).execute(borrowModel)
    }

    class deleteAsyncTask internal constructor(private var db: AppDatabase) : AsyncTask<BorrowModel, Void, Void>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: BorrowModel): Void? {
            db.itemAndPersonModel().deleteBorrow(params[0])
            return null
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Full crash log please. Your error could have million of reasons.

Comment: full error stacktrace added..

Comment: Error at `com.example.mrathi.livedataviewmodel.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:40)`. Which line is line#40 in `MainActivity.kt`?

Comment: try {
            viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BorrowedListViewModel::class.java)
        }catch ( e :Exception){
            e.toString()
        } this code